# Is there a way to add a specific Google Calendar as a forwarding address in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I wanted to create a filter in my Gmail account to forward specific calendar invites I receive to one of my other Google calendars (using its @group.calendar.google.com id).

Unfortunately, I can't add my Google Calendar as a forwarding address, because then Google sends an email with a verification code to that address and of course I can't access that email.

Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: What make you think that this is possible? Have you tried invite  this calendar to an event created in another calendar? Also,. please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]?